# How to disable touch detection while Google Map animation is running in android

Tags: java, android, touch, android-animation, google-maps-android-api-2

When I use the method below to execute an animation on google map, the animation ends if we touch the screen while animation is executing.

```
googleMap.animateCamera(
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition1),400,
                        new CancelableCallback() {

                              @Override
                              public void onFinish() {
                              }

                              @Override
                              public void onCancel() {
                              }
        });
```

I have tried disabling the touch detection using the code below

```
mapFragment.getView().setEnabled(false); 

googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

but the application detects touch despite the above lines. 
How do you correctly disable touch?

Comment: Some small tweaks in the question might make this an even better question. (How to .....)

Comment: @Joeblade can you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `setEnabled(false)` for the view instead use `setClickable(false)`

`mapFragment.getView().setClickable(false);`

This should work.

**EDIT**

Apparently this is bug filed here

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5114

as a work around you can deploy a transparent layer which will receive touch events instead of `MapFragment` .

Comment: I replaced the code with mapFragment.getView().setClickable(false); but it doesn't  make any change.

Comment: where are you putting this line ??

Comment: just before calling the animation '.animateCamera( ...'

Comment: how about not replacing the above line, but adding it along with your above 2 lines ?

Comment: I solved it using a boolean value; Change the boolean value while start and end of the animation. I check the value inside all touch events. :D

Comment: @SharpEdge `mapFragment.getView().setClickable(false);` did not disable map touch response. Ironically, `googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
` did.

Comment: @ImanAkbari this answer is 2 years old, so things must have been changed in the latest google map versions. Nonetheless `googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false)` should have worked for OP, but he must have been doing something wrong. Without seeing his whole code, this was the best guess.

Comment: @SharpEdge right. didn't notice that. then again, MapView has issues that date back to many years ago and they still don't take the time to fix them.

Comment: A quick example of how to add a layer on top of the mapView would be very helpful.

Comment: @lostintranslation this answer is almost 2 years old, I'm sure google must have enhanced the Map API to add something for this ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently available (yet it was requested [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5114)).

For now, you can put a view that's on top of the MapFragment, and add OnTouchListener for it that always returns true.

Whenever you wish to block touch events on the MapFragment, you make this view "visible". Otherwise, you set its visibility to "gone".

Comment: How do you put a view on top of the MapFragment?

Comment: Same way you put any view on top of another view. Put them both in the same ViewGroup (FrameLayout, for example). The order of them in it determines which is on top of which. If you put View1 and then View2 inside, then View2 is on top of View1 .

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it in case of adding the map programatically:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapFragmentContainerFl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/screen_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/screen_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locationDescriptionTv"
    android:background="#10000000">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/mapClickListenerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:translationZ="12dp"/>

</FrameLayout>

private fun initMapFragment() {
    val mapOptions = GoogleMapOptions().apply {
        zoomControlsEnabled(false)
        zoomGesturesEnabled(false)
        ambientEnabled(false)
        rotateGesturesEnabled(false)
        tiltGesturesEnabled(false)
        scrollGesturesEnabled(false)
        compassEnabled(false)
    }
    val mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions)
    childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.mapFragmentContainerFl, mapFragment)
            .commit()
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(::onMapReady)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
            mCameraMoveReason = reason;
            if (mCameraMoveReason != GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE)
                mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        }
    });



@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
    mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    }


  @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
}
```

mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled() does the enable/disable of touch gesture. Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:

in your `xml` file add respective attributes in your `map fragment` like this:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            map:uiCompass="false"
            map:uiRotateGestures="false"
            map:uiScrollGestures="false"
            map:uiTiltGestures="false"
            map:uiZoomControls="false"
            map:uiZoomGestures="false"
            tools:context=".rider.ui.fragment.RiderMapsFragment" />
```

and add the following line in your root layout:

```
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```